# SQL Query inside Widget

Tags: wp-query

I have a widget which contains the following code:

```
<? global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT name FROM wp_venues WHERE name ='".the_field('venue')."' ";
$info = $wpdb->get_var($querystr);
echo $info;
?>
```

What I need is to be able to use the information from the table and format it, so

```
Name:
Capacity:
Image:
Description:
```

At the moment I am only able to retrieve 1 field, I think get_rows would help but how am I able to separate the fields so I can format.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"SELECT name FROM wp_venues WHERE name ='".the_field('venue')."' ";` 
will only return the value of `the_field('venue')` which is already known.

`"SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name ='".the_field('venue')."' ";` will select the whole row with all fields.

Try too use `$wpdb->prepare` for security reasons.

With `$wpdb->get_row` you get the whole row as either an object, a numerically indexed array or an associative array. See the [codex on get_row](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row).

For example you could do the following:

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name = %s", the_field('venue')));
echo "Name: ".$row->name."\n";
echo "Capacity: ".$row->capacity."\n";
echo "Image: ".$row->image."\n";
echo "Description: ".$row->description."\n";
```

**Debugging**

Try what is mentioned in the codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors and turn on `WP_DEBUG` in wp-config.php.

In addition : `$wpdb->last_query` can be looked up to show the last query used. Retrieve the query, that is actually executed and try this query manually and see which results there are.

**Literature**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Hi yes, thanks but what I need is to separate the results into variables that I can format, at the moment it selects the row as a whole. Any ideas.

Comment: i edited the answer. do you see now, how you can access the values of the fields?

Comment: Hi yes I see how you have done it but for some reason it is not working for me. None of the echo variables are working , only the name which is because of the_field('venue').

Comment: which query are you using? what is the structure of the table? how does `$row` look? use `print_r($row)` to examine it.

Comment: I have tried both my query and yours above. The wp_venues table contains 5 columns, id, name, capacity, image, description.   print_r($row) not showing anything.

Comment: Do you get any errors when using this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors ? Is there any row in the table which actually matchs the query, that means have the name you are searching for? `get_row` returns `null` when no row is found.

Comment: No results are being returned so the quieres I have been trying have not been working. Strange. I have tried 4 or 5 now inside a PHP widget. Custom fields are displaying ok but not any query. I have even tried simply queries which I know have a result.

Comment: Any errors with http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors and WP_DEBUG true?

Comment: Debug True:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';   php-code-widget/execphp.php(44) : eval()'d code on line 2
AND
<?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?> shows nothing..

Comment: Try to solve this syntax error.

Comment: ok, yes..  <? global $wpdb;
$row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name = %s", the_field('venue')));
echo $row->name;

?>

ERROR: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
.. echo $row->name; throws the error message.

Comment: Then `get_row` did not found any row matching `the_field('venue')`. One other hint for debugging : `$wpdb->last_query` can be looked up to show the last query used. Retrieve the query, that is actually executed and try this query manually and see which results there are.

Comment: appreciate the help. So now I can see that the the_field('venue') is not being passed into the query. I assumed this was because it displays fine in the widget..

Comment: Is your problem regarding the question solved? If yes, dont forget to accept the answer.

Comment: hi unfortunately not. The custom field is not being passed into the query. 
The custom field can be echoed in the widget no problem but when used in the query it returns blank..

Comment: Then the problem is in the surrounding code. `$wpdb->prepare` should work as expected. Would you mind showing the surrounding code?

Comment: I have a PHP widget named php-code-widget... This is the exact code in the widget: <? global $wpdb; 
$row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name = %s", the_field('venue')));
echo "Name: ".$row->name."\n";
echo $wpdb->last_query;
?>
RESULT: Name: SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name = ''

Comment: You said, you can echo the custom field in the widget. How is this be done? When you really have access to the custom field while echoing, than at this point you could save the value to a variable and use this variable for the query.

Comment: Thank you very much... The problem is that I was using the_field instead of of get_field.. The full query to pull data from the database based on customfields is : <?  global $wpdb; 
$test = get_field('country');
$row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_venues WHERE name = %s", get_field('venue')));
 echo "Name: ".$row->name."\n"; ?>